# Creating a type that is an object of functions

Tags: typescript

I have some methods in TypeScript that are passed functions like `getJson`. In the application, this is an actual `getJson` function that does what it implies, but for testing purposes, `getJson` is mocked with a function that is the same shape as the original `getJson`.

I'm creating a type for these dependencies that currently looks like this:

```
import { getJson } from 'get-json';

interface Dependencies {
  getJson: typeof getJson;
  ... others ...
}
```

This works great, but I have quite a few dependencies and may need to add more, and there's a lot of redundancy with typing the function name and then `typeof -function-` again.

Is there any way to create the type that is an object with keys that match the function names whose values are the functions?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to consistently identity the scope those functions are in in order to "look them up" this way.  Instead, maybe make a `dependencies` object of the shape you are looking for, using [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)... and then get that object's type..  like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbke4W), maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typeof` on the whole object, and typescript will do the work for you:

```js
const function1 = (x: string) => undefined;
const function2 = (x: number, y: boolean) => 5;
const function3 = () => ({x: true, y: 5});

const myObject = {
  function1, 
  function2, 
  function3
}

type MyObjectType = typeof myObject;
```

Now MyObjectType is

```
type MyObjectType = {
    function1: (x: string) => undefined;
    function2: (x: number, y: boolean) => number;
    function3: () => {
        x: boolean;
        y: number;
    };
}
```

And you can apply that type to any other object.

### [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMKBLcBGGBeGAKADwC4ZoAnVMAcwEocA+GJAEwFM5LXmBuAKFEixEyNOABMOfMRhgEAWwBGrMgBoYATxIKQIADasAhmDrZGAVj4Do8JCnRgAzJLwnGeAN7SoZBKzWaYMwBfGj5+cGs5dQB5BQArVhRJd14YGxF7DDVhO3Fs21FHXiDeXih1AAdWGABZGPjEqAAVSurccqqQOBgo2ISUbiA)